# Can't re-partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

1. I just installed Ubuntu today and patched to latest version.
2. I downloaded the Windows ISO to install Windows too.
3. I understand I need to make a new partition.
4. Using Disks, I tried to resize my existing single partition from 1T to 500G but got a "target is busy" error
5. Using gParted, I tried to resize my existing single partition, but this time the GUI says the minimum size IS the current size, and stops me from even trying to shrink it.

**What is the next step to get Windows installed?**

Comment: You have to use gparted on live installer, so it is unmounted. You cannot work on mounted partitions. Best to let Windows create the partitions it needs as with UEFI it needs multiple partition. You did  install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. So only boot in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: I tried to study UEFI but now I am more confused.  I just want to install Windows in as few clear, simple steps as possible.  Are there no step-by-step instructions out there?

Comment: Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi Usually best to install Windows first in UEFI mode and then use its tools to shrink its main NTFS partition. Windows forums may have more details on Windows as this an Ubuntu question & answer site.